# unable to remove the borders occuring for header

Tags: html, css

I am trying to remove the borders around the header(in blue color), but could not
Kindly help me, please find attached the snpashot[border.jpg], need to remove the red border before the blue header, in the browser, in the css secion i see the border-collapse striked off

I don't need headers around the blue header

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

body {
  background-color: red;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-spacing: 0;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-style: none;
}

header {
  color: white;
  height: 10%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: blue;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border-spacing: 0 border-collapse: collapse;
  border-style: none;
}

header h1 {
  float: left;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  border-spacing: 0;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-style: none;
}

header ul {
  float: right;
  padding: 0;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  border-spacing: 0;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="container">
    <div id="logo">
      <h1>ACME WEB DESIGN</h1>
      <nav>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Hostel</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Company</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </div>

</header>

<section>
</section>
<footer>
</footer>
```

Comment: set body margin to 0

Comment: @t.m. thank u it wroked